# how to insert collection records from one database to another database using mongojs

Tags: node.js, migrate, mongojs

I am trying to get records of one collection which exist in 'fromdb' and insert that records to another collection of 'todb'. Both databases have same schema structure same collections, I just want to merge both records for particular collection.

Script which I wrote is:

```
var config = require('./mydb');
var collections = ['addresses'];
var todb = require('mongojs').connect(config.todb, collections);
var fromdb = require('mongojs').connect(config.fromdb, collections);

exports.up = function(next) {
  fromdb.addresses.find().forEach(function(err, d) {
    if(!err && d){
      todb.addresses.insert(d);      
    }
    if(!d)
      next();
  });
};

exports.down = function(next) {
  next();
};
```

but the problem is there is no error after execution and am unable to insert records in todb. Will you please suggest what am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the .forEach method from a mongo cursor, which [takes a single argument](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach). So in your code the data is being passed to the `err` variable and the `d` variable is left as undefined.

If you want to keep the error handling you're best to use a regular callback, mongojs will call toArray for you on the data but you'll still have a forEach method:

```
// Instead of fromdb.addresses.find().forEach(function(err, d) {
fromdb.addresses.find(function(err, results) {
  results.forEach(function(d) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much it helps.